# Problem with Xpath | Two buttons with the same text

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to click an BUY NOW button using a xpaths builder, but this case is a bit special. I try to click on a dropdown screen, but in that same UI (back) there is still an  button, then the xpath clicks on the back button instead of the new OK button that has been displayed in the new overlay window.
Ideally, I would like to add to the xpath a way to click only on the visible elements.

The xpath I am using is:

```
"fn:reverse(((.//*[(@android:contentDescription | u/android:text[not(../@android:editable='true')])[fn:glob(., 'BUY NOW')]])[1]/ancestor-or-self::*)"
```

I explain again, in a nutshell:

> The XML of the UI has two entries with OK text that corresponds to a
> button that I have to click on. When I use the xpath it clicks on the
> first OK instead of clicking on the second OK which corresponds to the
> overlay window.

Any idea how I could solve this?

XML file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rpsKXq2ibptut726h3EmuUQFgbL5Lf94/view?usp=sharing